# setting div's height to the bottom of parent div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 2 divs in parent div:

```css
.core {
  height: 200px;
  /* 200% px is just for showcase, in my app I am using % of another div... */
  background-color: yellow;
}

.boxName {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.boxName span {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.basicInfo {
  position: relative;
  /*margin-bottom and bottom don't change anything*/
  /*height sets height but including height of the title
        height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0%;*/
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="core">
  <div class="boxName"><span>Title</span></div>
  <div class="basicInfo">
    How to set height of this div to the bottom of core div?
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to make sure that basicInfo div ends where core div ends (bottoms are aligned).

I tried numerous things from other posts, such as display: flex, bottom: 0%, margin-bottom: 0%, etc.

I would be happy to hear from you what I am doing wrong. I would rather not 
use position: absolute in this case.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbhkq9dm/1/).

Thanks,
Marcin

Comment: use `overflow:hidden` on `.core`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use flex:

```css
.core {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;


  /* add these */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.boxName {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.boxName span {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.basicInfo {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;


  /* add this (makes the second div grow to fill the rest of the column) */
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="core">
  <div class="boxName"><span>Title</span></div>
  <div class="basicInfo">
    How to set height of this div to the bottom of core div?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calc` to achieve this. here i have subtract `18px` from the `100%` because of `title` has height of `18px`

```css
.core{
  height: 200px; /* 200% px is just for showcase, in my app I am using % of another div... */
  background-color: yellow;
}
.boxName{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.boxName span { 
    background-color: black; 
    color: white;
}

.basicInfo{    
    position: relative;
    /*margin-bottom and bottom don't change anything*/
    /*height sets height but including height of the title    
    margin-bottom: 0%;*/
    height: calc(100% - 18px);
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="core">
     <div class="boxName"><span>Title</span></div>
     <div class="basicInfo">
        How to set height of this div to the bottom of core div?
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this assumes the title only stays as one line of text and is a fixed 18px in size

Comment: Hi, yes, I was thinking about calc, but it won't help if the height of the parent is not 200px but something else. Can calc get arguments such as div's height?

Comment: using flex is much convenient approach in this case.

Comment: @Pete that i have explained in my answer

Comment: @DhavalJardosh its upto the questioner which solution will be best for them

Comment: Yes sir, the solution provided by you I'm not saying that's wrong. What if there is a sub-title, margin, padding to it? You will need to recalculate the height in `px`. Which isn't convenient in most cases.

Comment: This also won't work if you remove the demo height property

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height restriction on the `.core` div

```
<div class="core">
  <div class="contain">
   <div class="boxName"><span>Title</span></div>
   <div class="basicInfo">
      How to set height of this div to the bottom of core div?
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>


.core{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.boxName{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.boxName span { 
    background-color: black; 
    color: white;
}

.basicInfo{    
    position: relative;
    /*margin-bottom and bottom don't change anything*/
    /*height sets height but including height of the title
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;*/
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the size of core since it is a part of the bigger window. But still, thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Give the baiscInfo class the style showed below -

```
.basicInfo{
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
```

}

That is what is doing great for me!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.core {
  height: 200px;width:100%;
  /* 200% px is just for showcase, in my app I am using % of another div... */
  background-color: yellow;
  position:absolute;
}

.boxName {
  display: block;
  height:auto;
}

.boxName span {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.basicInfo {
  position: relative;
  /*margin-bottom and bottom don't change anything*/
  /*height sets height but including height of the title
        height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0%;*/
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 30%;
  top:145px;

  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="core">
  <div class="boxName"><span>Title</span></div>
  <div class="basicInfo">
    How to set height of this div to the bottom of core div?
  </div>
</div>
```

Check whether this helps. try to adjust 'top:145px'

Answer (score -1):

```css
.core{
  height: 200px; /* 200% px is just for showcase, in my app I am using % of another div... */
  background-color: yellow;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.boxName{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.boxName span { 
    background-color: black; 
    color: white;
}

.basicInfo{    
    position: relative;
    /*margin-bottom and bottom don't change anything*/
    /*height sets height but including height of the title    
    margin-bottom: 0%;*/
    /*height: 100%;*/
    /*bottom: 0%;*/
    width: 30%;
    background-color: green;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="core">
     <div class="boxName"><span>Title</span></div>
     <div class="basicInfo">
        How to set height of this div to the bottom of core div?
     </div>
</div>
```